# How to fix Liquorix problems

Tags: linux, gui, user-interface

I installed liquorix as a lubuntu kernel to improve the performance of the computer in tasks that require graphics processing, such as simulators or games, the problem is that you see lines like glitches when a graphic object is behind another, how can I solve this problem ?

Equipment details:

[image]

Error example:

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a non-liquorix kernel?  or with a different version of the liquorix kernel?   What version of mesa are you running - kernel 5.11 had significant changes to intel graphics drivers (so may require a mesa update to 21.1).   Note: this is just general troubleshooting tips - I am not an expert on graphics and especially not on intel graphics or mesa (I mostly use nvidia GPUs with nvidia's proprietary driver, which doesn't use mesa)

Comment: @cas maybe that is the answer to the problem, since when viewing the kernel version with "uname -a" appears "Linux moro-system 5.11.0-16.1-liquorix-amd64 # 1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT liquorix 5.11-30ubuntu1 ~ groovy ( 2021-04-21) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU / Linux ", how can I update to the new version?

Comment: Updating to a pre-release version of mesa (or anything, really) can be complicated. and i have no idea how to do it on lubuntu.  On debian, I'd look in backports, or maybe **very** carefully try installing selected packages from unstable or experimental - this can lead to a real mess or a broken system...definitely not recommended.   Your best option is probably to downgrade to a liquorix 5.10 kernel, which shouldn't need a new mesa.    BTW, I used to run liquorix kernels on debian years ago...IMO the touted performance/responsiveness benefits are exaggerated and over-rated.

Comment: FYI, to see what versions of, e.g., libgl1-mesa-dri you have installed or available, run `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri`.   As I said above, I wouldn't recommend trying to upgrade to pre-release versions.  Better to downgrade your kernel and wait for an update to the lubuntu packages.  With \*ubuntu, it's less than 6 months until the 2110 release.